# Получить $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  на js

Tags: php, javascript

Хочу получить `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` только на js... прогуглил, ничего похожего! Как получить?

Comment: А как вы это себе представляете? Только если ajax запрос посылать.

Comment: **window.location** - чем не подходит?

Comment: Какая цель? Получить путь к файлу скрипта или перезагрузить страницу?

Comment: $PHP_SELF - Путь к выполняемой программе (/index.php)
Хотел получить то же самое, только на js... спасибо за комментарии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
location.pathname
```

Будьте добры, оперируйте чем-нибудь ближе к терминам. Я тоже успел подумать, что надо аяксовую связку делать.

Comment: Спасибо! пожалуй, единственный форум, на который можно положиться!)